# cmake - How to link separate libraries which are on the same directory level together?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

I have a project with the given tree structure:

```
.
├── app.cpp
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── Module.hpp
├── libs
│   ├── LibA
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── include
│   │   │   └── LibA.hpp
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   └── LibA.cpp
│   │   └── tests
│   │       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │       └── LibA-ut.cpp
│   └── LibB
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── include
│       │   └── LibB.hpp
│       ├── src
│       │   └── LibB.cpp
│       └── tests
│           ├── CMakeLists.txt
│           └── LibB-ut.cpp
├── src
│   └── Module.cpp
└── tests
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── Module-ut.cpp
```

I would like to link **LibB** into **LibA** so LibA can use LibB internally:

```
#pragma once

#include "LibB.hpp"

class LibA {
public:
private:
    LibB libB_ {};
};
```

In **Module** we will use **LibA**(which includes **LibB**) and also **LibB** alone. Then app.cpp creates an object of class **Module** and uses it.

This is the **CMakeLists.txt** of the project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Module)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/03597a01ee50ed33e9dfd640b249b4be3799d395.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

set(SRC
    src/Module.cpp
)

set(LIBS
    LibA-lib
    LibA-lib
)

set(FLAGS -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -Wconversion -O3)


add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}-lib STATIC ${SRC})
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME}-lib PRIVATE ${FLAGS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-lib ${LIBS})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}-lib PUBLIC ./include)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} app.cpp)
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${FLAGS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}-lib)

enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(tests)
add_subdirectory(libs/LibA)
add_subdirectory(libs/LibB)
```

For **LibA** and **LibB** CMakeLists.txt are almost the same:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(LibA)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(SRC
    src/LibA.cpp
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}-lib STATIC ${SRC})
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME}-lib PRIVATE ${FLAGS})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}-lib PUBLIC ./include)

enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(tests)
```

At the moment when I try to use **LibB** in that way I encounter the problem:

```
LibA.hpp:3:10: fatal error: LibB.hpp: No such file or directory
    3 | #include "LibB.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated
```

My main question is: **How to solve that kind of link problem issues in this given scenario?** I came up with a little workaround which solves the problem:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(LibA)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(SRC
    src/LibA.cpp
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}-lib STATIC ${SRC})
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME}-lib PRIVATE ${FLAGS})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}-lib PUBLIC ./include ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/LibB/include)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-lib LibB-lib)

enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(tests)
```

Comment: Your `libA` uses `libB`. So you need to link them: `target_link_libraries(libA PUBLIC libB)`.